# UITableView Add Rows At The Bottom Using Parsing Another Page

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am working on an example project for learning purposes. I have successfully parsed a wordpress site by parsing RSS feed using NSXMLParser. The custom cell includes thumbnail, title, author and published date of posts.

Currently its showing the first page of feed containing 10 posts. I can access the second page of the feed http://sitename.com/feed/?paged=2 and and third page by putting /?paged=3, if i type them in the browser.

What i want to do is when user scrolls down to the bottom, it uses the second page feed url and show the posts at the bottom and so on. Can anyone guide me how to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coneybeare has the right idea on how to set it up.

Use AFNetworking, it'll make your life way easier.

I would have an int counter that keeps track of which URL has been last called. Then, as soon as the user gets to the bottom most cell (which you know via a delegate method), I would increase the int by 1, and then append that to the String that represents the URL. You can use the stringByAppendingString method for that.

Now you have a new String with the correct url, and you can fire off a new request, and append the data to what you already have. Then you can do [self.tableView reloadData] to refresh the table.

Comment: The logic you have provided seems very right but i think i will need an example.

Answer (score 3):

To make an infinite scroller, you need to know when to start fetching the new items. There are many ways to do this, but the best place is to hook into the `UITableViewDelegate`'s methods. When `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called, check if the row is the last in your data store. If it is, make the call for the new data, then append it to the old data and refresh your view. You can also hook into the table views scroller to see when it it X percent scrolled to the bottom to make this call.

Comment: I am using NSURLRequest to grab the content and parse it, what i am unable to do is how can i change the url each time the user scrolls down at the bottom.

Comment: You need to keep an instance variable in your controller, then increment it each time you fetch to construct the string.

Comment: @Jessica It is generally best to award the correct answer to the first person who wrote it :/

Comment: @ConeyyBeare I just awarded the correct answer to the one that i was better able to understand :/